# Instance variables in extension vs implementation

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

In Objective-C, for instance variables that one doesn't want to put in the header file and, one can put them either in the class extension:

```
@interface MyClass () {
  NSString *myInstanceVariable;
}
// ...
@end
```

or in the class implementation:

```
@implementation MyClass {
  NSString *myInstanceVariable;
}
// ...
@end
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you posted, myInstanceVariable is declared in the interface but not explicitly declared as private so it's protected, not private.  Protected is the default.

In the second example you posted, myInstanceVariable is declared in the implementation rather than the interface and so it is private.

My preference would be to list it as @private in the interface.

Comment: Not true. In the first case it is also private.

Comment: Apologies, I read this as a regular class interface when it's actually an anonymous category.  The language needs more annotations, like \@extended or \@category.